# PHP Session-Based flash message

Tags: php, flash, session

I'm trying to create a Session-Based flash message in PHP:

In register.php page, I set the session as follow:

```
$_SESSION['flash'] = 'Registered';
```

Then, after redirecting user to the home page, I printed the flash message:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['flash'])) {
   echo $_SESSION['flash'];
   unset($_SESSION['flash']);
}
```

The session is started in both pages.
The problem is:
I get the flash message in the home page only if I remove the unset function, and then the message is always printed.

Comment: maybe youre homepage is being executed TWICE, so you delete the message in the first execution run, and then there's nothing to print on the second time.

Comment: can you put more code plz ..need to see how you redirecting.

Comment: I'm sure that the home page is executed ONCE. Otherwise, for redirecting I'm using header('Location: Home.php') exactly after setting the session. However, for more information, the code where i'm printing the message is within a file Message.php and then this file is included in another file contains the HTML header this last is included in every page. After hours of testing, I found that when I move the Message.php  file from the Header file to the Home page directly the problem is solved but this is not really a good practice because I want the Message.php file in all pages, so any ideas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just solved my problem by adding exit after redirecting user to escape the execution of the register page, so the session won't be unset in the current page before using it in the next page.

Answer (score 9):

I wrote a library just for this type of issues: https://github.com/tamtamchik/simple-flash.

Once you have it installed you can do this:

```
// put message not session
flash('Some error message', 'error');

// print it after redirect
echo flash()->display();
```

It'll generate [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) friendly alert messages.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

Please note that session_unset just clears out the sesison for usage. The session is still on the users computer. Note that by using session_unset, the variable still exists.

Using session_unset in tandem with session_destroy however, is a much more effective means of actually clearing out data. As stated in the example above, this works very well, cross browser:

```
<?php
session_unset();
session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think that you understood the problem, exactly what happening is: the session is unset before even used so I don't get the message in the page. However, when I remove unset, I get always the message where me I want it to disappear once I refresh the page.