# Getting output from stored procedure in PHP

Tags: php, sql, db2

I'm calling a stored procedure in php right now, and the third parameter of the procedure is an OUT param so it should be getting the output

When I run this:

```
function createNameRecord($firstName,$lastName){
    try{
        $sql = "CALL schema.CREATE_RECORD(?,?,?)";
        $values = [$firstName,$lastName,$returnID];
        return DB::connection('odbc')->select($sql,$values);
        dd($returnID);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

The procedure runs properly and reloads the page, and when I check the database then the record was successfully created. However, I need the output variable which is the ID of the created record and I need it returned for a function that runs afterwards.

SO since this runs, successfully creates the record and reloads the page then how can I dump the output `$returnID` so that I can verify that it's storing my returned ID? The dump and die above doesn't work, potentially because of the page reload.

What's the best way to verify the return ID?

Comment: If you're simply debugging, prevent the redirect, and just echo the variable/exit. If you need to preserve the field between page loads, store it in a session. See [Flash Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015213/php-session-based-flash-message)

Comment: You are returning before getting to dd($returnID); Put that line first, or remove the return from line 5, and put it at the start of line 6.

Comment: @Millar248 I would have to execute the proc before getting the return ID, so you're saying remove "return" and put it before the dump/die?

Comment: I'm just saying that, to my knowledge, return ends a function. I don't know what "dd()" is doing, but if your code is working, and you're expecting dd to be sending back data, I doubt it will do that after a return is called. If it were me, I would do this:
try {
//...
DB::connection('odbc')->select($sql,$values);
dd($returnID);
}catch(Exception $e){
return false;
}
return true;

Comment: @FrankerZ the controller that hits this function is using return back() at the end and the form is submitting with a submit button. can you give me an example of how to execute this procedure and flash the ID in a message once successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as your function sees `return`, the function will no longer execute any code after that line. In this case `dd($returnID);` will never get executed. If you're simply debugging, just remove `return`, and let `dd()` output/die:

```
function createNameRecord($firstName,$lastName){
    try{
        $sql = "CALL schema.CREATE_RECORD(?,?,?)";
        $values = [$firstName,$lastName,$returnID];
        DB::connection('odbc')->select($sql,$values);
        dd($returnID);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

In this case, you're not caring about the return value (Whatever is calling `createNameRecord`), as you just want your script to end/die.

If it's still reloading the page, then your catch statement is likely being executed, and you should debug that as well:

```
function createNameRecord($firstName,$lastName){
    try{
        $sql = "CALL schema.CREATE_RECORD(?,?,?)";
        $values = [$firstName,$lastName,$returnID];
        DB::connection('odbc')->select($sql,$values);
        dd($returnID);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        dd($e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try that, but it still refreshes the page, I think that's my issue. The controller driving this is using return back() if that makes a difference, and the form as an input submit button. So it is still successfully creating the record with your change but the page reloads and my ID doesn't get dumped

Comment: You were right, it still inserts the record but I get an invalid cursor state on the procedure and it shoes the $returnID as being null

Answer (score 2):

I am new to the community and don't fully know how to guide you but what if you tried [mysqli_real_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-query.php) and retrieved the results as the doc says:

> Executes a single query against the database whose result can then be
>   retrieved or stored using the mysqli_store_result() or
>   mysqli_use_result() functions.